# Pass Argument to Function Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a tab bar using `react-mdl` library. I have an `activeTab` property in my state object to determine which tab was clicked and render the right information.

I have used an onChange method on the tabs holder to fetch the tab id from user click events and passed the id to my function where the activeTab property will be set from events.

This is what I have done so far:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Tabs, Tab } from 'react-mdl';
import './index.css';

class Projects extends Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        activeTab: 0
    }

}

handleTabChange(tabId){
    this.setState({
        activeTab: tabId
    });
    console.log(this.state);
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="">
            <Tabs
                activeTab={this.state.activeTab}
                onChange={ () => this.handleTabChange(tabId)}>
                <Tab>Android</Tab>
                <Tab>Web</Tab>
                <Tab>Full Stack</Tab>
            </Tabs>
        </div>
    );
}

}

export default Projects;
```

but when I build the project it crashes in browser with this error:

```
./src/components/Projects/Projects.js
Line 28:  'tabId' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

How can I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: as the error says `tabId` is an undefined variable. where did you declare it inside the `render` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. From the `react-mdl` [examples](https://tleunen.github.io/react-mdl/components/tabs/):

You need to pass the tabId as a parameter to the `onChange` binding.

```
onChange={ (tabId) => this.handleTabChange(tabId)}
```

Full example:

```
<div className="demo-tabs">
   <Tabs activeTab={this.state.activeTab} 
         onChange={(tabId) => this.setState({ activeTab: tabId })} ripple>
      <Tab>Starks</Tab>
      <Tab>Lannisters</Tab>
      <Tab>Targaryens</Tab>
   </Tabs>
   <section>
        <div className="content">Content for the tab: {this.state.activeTab}</div>
   </section>
</div>
```